# Alternate Triangle Inequality: Instead of $\Big|\,|x| - |y|\,\Big| \leq |x-y|$ can we use $|x| - |y| \leq |x-y|$?

Tags: triangle-inequality

Does the Alternate Triangle Inequality hold if we do not use the outer mod?

That is, instead of $$\Big|\,|x| - |y|\,\Big| \leq |x-y|$$

can we use the following? $$|x| - |y| \leq |x-y|$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is true, but less precise :)

Comment: Yes you can but the latter is a weak version.

Comment: Note that $|r| \geq r$ for $r \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Though not so obvious at first glance, the two statements are actually equivalent (and true), so you can use either one you want.

Comment: Note that $|a|\leq b$ means $-b \leq a \leq b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
  T_\text{w}&:& |x|-|y| \leq |x-y|\quad&\forall x,y\in S
\end{align}$$
is equivalent to
$$\begin{align}
  T_\text{s}&:& \bigl||x|-|y|\bigr| \leq |x-y|\quad&\forall x,y\in S.
\end{align}$$

Proof: from $T_\text{s}$ follows $T_\text{w}$ immediately because $a\leq|a|$ holds always. In the other direction, we need to make a case distinction:

- If $|x|\geq|y|$, then $\bigl||x|-|y|\bigr| = |x|-|y|$ and thus $T_\text{s}$ *is* $T_\text{w}$.
- If $|x|<|y|$, then $$ \bigl||x|-|y|\bigr| = |y|-|x| =: |\tilde{x}|-|\tilde{y}|, $$ which, since $T_\text{w}$ quantifies over all $x,y\in S$, is $$ \leq|\tilde{x}-\tilde{y}| = |y-x| = |x-y|, $$ which was to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

$|x-y| \ge |x|-|y|$ will always be true and it will be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

just check that
$$ |(x - y) + y| \leqslant |x - y| + |y| \implies |x| - |y| \leqslant |x - y| $$
$\color{red}{\text{The inequality }} \color{blue}{ ||x| - |y|| \leqslant |x - y| \text{ is the general case } }$